# cl-pdf output error

Tags: lisp, pdf-generation, common-lisp, outputstream

I'm trying to use `cl-pdf` for some fairly basic PDF generation, but I'm getting tripped up at the examples (which is embarassing to say the least).

When I run the first example included in the package

```
(defun example1 (&optional (file #P"/tmp/ex1.pdf"))
  (pdf:with-document ()
    (pdf:with-page ()
      (pdf:with-outline-level ("Example" (pdf:register-page-reference))
        (let ((helvetica (pdf:get-font "Helvetica")))
          (pdf:in-text-mode
           (pdf:set-font helvetica 36.0)
           (pdf:move-text 100 800)
           (pdf:draw-text "cl-pdf: Example 1"))
          (pdf:translate 230 500)
          (loop repeat 150
         for i = 0.67 then (* i 1.045)
         do (pdf:in-text-mode
             (pdf:set-font helvetica i)
             (pdf:set-rgb-fill (/ (random 255) 255.0)
                               (/ (random 255) 255.0)
                               (/ (random 255) 255.0))
             (pdf:move-text (* i 3) 0)
             (pdf:show-text "cl-typesetting"))
           (pdf:rotate 13)))))
    (pdf:write-document file)))
```

by running `(example1 #P"/home/inaimathi/Desktop/ex1.pdf")` it gives me this error

```
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/inaimathi/Desktop/test.pdf" 
{CF9D931}> is not a binary output stream. 
    [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

The same thing happens when I call `(example1)`, or when I do

```
(with-open-file 
     (test-file #P"/home/inaimathi/Desktop/ex1.pdf" 
     :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create) 
   (example1 test-file))
```

Finally, if I try

```
(with-open-file 
     (test-file #P"/home/inaimathi/Desktop/ex1.pdf" 
     :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create 
     :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)) 
   (example1 test-file))
```

I get the error

```
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/inaimathi/Desktop/test.pdf" 
{D197C99}> is not a character output stream.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

Is there a way to declare a `binary character stream`? How do I get simple output out of `cl-pdf`? I'm using SBCL straight out of the debian repos (which is 1.0.29, I think), in case it matters.

Comment: I'm looking at my stuff (uses cl-typesetting, which calls cl-pdf's write-document) and it looks fine. Is it possible you're running into permissions problems?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a permission error; regular calls to `with-open-file` still succeed when I try to write to the same file as above, and I set the target directory to 777 earlier just to check if it helps. What CL implementation are you using, and what version of cl-pdf do you run? (I downloaded the "cl-pdf-current" tarball from the fractal concept site, not sure how current it is)

Comment: Sadly, the Debian repositories are not very up to date (almost no Linux distribution's CL repositories are, except the Gentoo Lisp overlay).  I would recommend to get a current SBCL.

Comment: Tried out the latest SBCL binary from their project page (which is 1.0.49), and it generated the same error when I tried to define and call `example1`; `this is not a binary stream`. So it's not (just) the version of SBCL.

Comment: I'm using SBCL, and my cl-pdf and cl-typesetting are from svn, dated 2009-08-07.

Comment: Just did a git-svn checkout from http://www.fractalconcept.com:8000/public/open-source/cl-pdf, uninstalled the asdf version and installed the checkout. That fixed it. As a sidenote, I kept SBCL 1.0.29, so whatever the issue was, it was in the version of cl-pdf I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(setf pdf:*compress-streams* nil)` should help. It's trying to write binary data to a character stream, and while that works on LispWorks and some other systems, it doesn't work everywhere and particularly not on SBCL.

Comment: Which makes sense given the error output I was getting. I think I still have the old version of `cl-pdf` on my machine at home; I'll test this out when I get out of the office.

Comment: Turns out I don't still have the old version. Oddly, having installed the SVN checkout, if I just `(asdf-install:uninstall 'cl-pdf)`, then `(asdf-install:install 'cl-pdf)` (which downloads the cl-pdf-current tarball from fractalconcept), and try the example function, it still works. I assume there's state left behind from the old install that `asdf-install:uninstall` doesn't get rid of. I'll try it on a clean machine today to see what happens.

Comment: Yup, it works. If you use the default version installed by ASDF, it runs properly as long as you evaluate the above first. Oddly enough, you need to do this even if you set `*compress-streams*` to `nil` in config.lisp

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: **asdf-install is unmaintained and deprecated.**  It is best to use [Quicklisp](https://www.cliki.net/Quicklisp).  To install Quicklisp, you'll need to download it:

```
$ curl -O https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
```

Then add `cl-pdf` to your lisp installation:

```
$ sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp
* (quicklisp-quickstart:install)
* (ql:quickload "vecto")
* (ql:add-to-init-file)
* (exit)
```

Now all you need to do is add

```lisp
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp") ; if it installed in the default location
```

to your `.lisp` file, and you can then add

```
(ql:quickload "cl-pdf")
```

---

EDIT: This is what I ended up doing. The solution by xach above would also work.

In the end I had to `wget http://www.fractalconcept.com/download/cl-pdf-current.tgz` and install that.

For the newbs (since I remember how frustrating it is for someone new to Common Lisp to hear "just do a checkout and install it"):

1.Do the checkout as above (I assume you've done this in your home directory from now on)

2.Type in `tar xvzf cl-pdf-current.tgz` (the point is to get a tarball of the folder. You can do this through the GUI too, it makes no difference)

3.Hop into your SBCL prompt and enter

```
(require 'asdf)
(require 'asdf-install)
```

4.If you already installed `cl-pdf` using `(asdf-install:install 'cl-pdf)`, then you'll need to enter `(asdf-install:uninstall  'cl-pdf)`

5.Type `(asdf-install:install "/home/[your home folder name]/cl-pdf-current.tgz")`

I got one compilation error throughout this process, which I just selected [Accept] for. It still seems to work fine.

Hopefully the upcoming release of [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) will reduce the need for this sort of package hunting.